# Downloading Images with PowerShell script

Tags: shell, powershell

I normally use a PowerShell script to download bulk CSV of images, but I have a new URL that displays the images very oddly. Could I modify this script to allow for these image URLs?

Example URLs:

https://www.example.com/core/media/media.nl?id=12&c=23&h=b944f2f81326d0bb
https://www.example.com/core/media/media.nl?id=15&c=42&h=7ed23c91f3574fc9

and the current script...

```cs
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(
    'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll') | Out-Null 

$FileName = "C:\Temp\test.txt";
$Loc = "C:\Temp\Images\"
$ImageName = ""

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$content = Get-Content $FileName
foreach ($line in $content) {
    $Image = $Loc + $line.Substring($line.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)
    $url = $line

    Write-Host $url
    Write-Host $Image

    $wc.DownloadFile($url, $Image)
}

Write-Jost "Finished successfully."
```

Answer (score 1):

A file name on Windows can't contain `?`, `*`, `"`, `\` characters, so filter them out:

```
$Image = $Loc + ($line.Substring($line.LastIndexOf("/") + 1) -replace '[?*"\\]', '_')
```

To get the real redirected file name from a dynamic URL process the `Content-Disposition` header:

```
$tmp = [IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $tmp)

$Image = "$($wc.ResponseHeaders['Content-Disposition'])" -replace '^.*?filename=', ''
if (!$Image) {
    $Image = $line.Substring($line.LastIndexOf("/") + 1) -replace '[?*"\\]', '_'
}
Move $tmp (Join-Path $Loc $Image)
```

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, we were looking at this differently. While yours works (after renaming it with a jpg extension), I was looking to pull the real image info. What I mean by that, is if you enter the top URL above, and right click, save as.... you get the actual file name - 027789-352816.jpg. Is there any way Powershell can grab that?

Comment: Works - oddly, how I have it integrated, it always throws these   Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2"
Parameter name: address"
At line:15 char:1
+ $wc.DownloadFile($url, $tmp)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At line:17 char:13
+ $Image = "$($wc.ResponseHeaders['Content
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOpera
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: I have no idea. Debug the code in PowerShell ISE: open the script, click a line inside the code, press F9 to set a breakpoint, run the script (F5), then step through the code (F10) and point the mouse over the variables to see the values.